# How can I join two tables using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entity classes **Medicine** and **Medicine Group**. A medicine belongs to a group . A group has more than one medicine. The relationship from medicine to group is **one to one** from group to medicine is **one to many**.

I have created the entity classes with the following properties

```
@Entity
public class Medicine {
    @Id
    String medicineId;
    String medicineName;
    int inStock;
    String lifetimeSupply;
    String lifetimeSales;
    String howToUse;
    String sideEffects;
 //their getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class MedicineGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int groupId;
    String groupName;
    String groupDescription;

  //their getters and setters.
}
```

In **MySQL** in the Medicine table I have a column called **groupId** which is a foreign key to the group table.

Normally in MySQL I could write a join statement like this

```
SELECT medicine_id ,medicine_name ,in_stock ,lifetime_supply, lifetime_sales, how_to_use, side_effects , group_name FROM medicine JOIN medicine_group on medicine.group_id = medicine_group.group_id;
```

In the above join I am able to get the group name column from the group table. **How can I achieve this using JPA**.
If I add a field to the medicine class like this

```
@OneToOne
MedicineGroup medicineGroup;
```

when I do a get request I get an error *Unknown column 'medicine0_.medicine_group_group_id' in 'field list'* . **How is the field unknown** yet I have a column called group_id in the medicine table?

**How can I achieve a way in which if I perform a get request I get the medicine information and also the group with which it is associated with?** **Please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple join on the attribute:

```
SELECT m.medicineId ,m.medicineName ,m.inStock ,m.lifetimeSupply, m.lifetimeSales, m.howToUse, m.sideSffects , mg.groupName 
FROM medicine m join m.medicineGroup mg;
```

and use attribute names, not column names

Comment: Isn't there a way JPA actually has a way to get the above results without actually writing a query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select m from medicine m left join fetch m.medecineGroup
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.